# How do I add the picamera library into Eclipse?

Tags: python, pip

All the steps I can find are to add `picamera` using `pip` and `apt-get` to auto install it but I'm using windows.  I am also using python 3.4 but I don't think that should make a difference.  The errors I get are

```
ImportError: No module named 'picamera'
```

when I compile.

How do I manually import a module into Eclipse or get Eclipse to recognize picamera?  I downloaded the module from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/picamera/1.10) which contains a `setup.py` file that seems to function primarily on linux or BSD flavors.

Do I have to use a linux environment to use the python `picamera` module?  Seems silly.  It wouldn't makes sense as it's python-based which is language dependent and OS agnostic.

Comment: `pip` comes alongside python3 when you install python. Where are you trying to execute the `pip` command. Is `pip` in your path

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows to install using `pip` on windows

Comment: perfect!  I didn't realize pip came with all python installs.  I found it in the scripts folders and ran "pip install picamera"   easy as pi!  Thank you so much.  This, as most issues, took way too long than it needed.